# Skip quotes in regex

Tags: regex, string

I have the following regex

```
val=\"(?<val>.*?)\"
```

it works ok for `val="value"`

Now I need regex that will match `val="value"` and `val=value`

Could you please help? I don't understand how to build such regex. I have tried the following but no success

```
val=[^"](?<val>.*?)[^"]
```

update

it seems works `val=(?:[^"])*(?<val>.*?)(?:[^"]|")*` but I'm not sure that it is correct

Comment: What about `val=value"` ? or `val="value` or `val="val=value"`? Just out of curiosity, what are you building? And what language do you use (knowing regex differs from lang to lang)

Comment: I'm building regex for link header `rel=next`  https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5988#section-5. There should be `rel` instead of `val` in my question

Comment: **Never** use regex to parse HTML. Use a DOM parser.

Comment: it is not my case. I need regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture the optional opening quote, and require it to be present at the end of the match.

```
val=(\"?)(?<val>.*?)\1
```

The back-reference `\1` recalls the text which matched the first parenthesized expression.

Obviously, if you have code which depends on the order of grouped parentheses, you need to refer to the second group to get `val`; but of course you are likely referring to it by name already (otherwise why use a named group?)

The expression `[^"]` matches a character which *isn't* a quote, so it's completely wrong here.

Of course, when there aren't any quotes, the expression `.*?` will match the empty string if there isn't a trailing context which forces it to match something longer. Perhaps you can use something like

```
val=(\"?)(?<val>.*?)\1(\s|$)
```

but this will obviously depend on what exactly you are hoping to match and in what context. If not this then maybe you can constrain the value so that you can use a greedy match instead? For instance,

```
val=(\"?)(?<val>[^\"]*)\1
```

Comment: it doesn't match `val=value`. See https://regex101.com/r/1aAxkB/1

Comment: I meant to add an explanation but you were too quick (-: See update now.